# headless browser mode and normal mode behave differently

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools

Send keys event to a dom element, headless browser mode and normal mode behave differently, headless browser just opens a new tab

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath"));
                 element.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.META, Keys.RETURN));
```

in headless, to about:blank.
in normal, to link tab.

Comment: Please share ALL the relevant code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.